# Anything special to consider when cloning an HD to an SSD?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, ssd, cloning, mkfs

I would like to move from an HD to an SSD. Is there anything special to consider here? For example:

- Different recommended fstab settings
- `mkfs` or partition tools behaving differently when operating on an HD vs on an SSD -- so I'd end up with a file system optimized for an HD on my SSD.

Comment: I clone systems on a daily basis, and there is no measurable difference between *just dumped* HDD onto an SSD, or slightly optimized dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No, not really

Unless you are operating a RAID, no special measures must be taken.

As other answers said, SSDs tend to have a block size of 4k byte instead of 512 byte. For years partition tools are aware of this, hence the partitions are aligned to 1 MiB starts. You can check with `fdisk -l /dev/sdx`: If the output looks like this, you are fine:

```
Disk /dev/sdx: xxx GiB, xxx bytes, xxx sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdx1       2048       xxx       xxx  xxxx xx xxxx
```

Notice how this SSD has 4 kB blocks, yet the numbers represent "sectors" of 512 byte.

As for the `fstab` settings, there once was a debate of explicitly requesting usage of the TRIM command. Current Linuxes are already pre-configured to operate in sensible manner (as discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034169/is-trim-enabled-on-my-ubuntu-18-04-installation)).

Of course, copying the data with `dd` is much easier if the SSD is alt least as big as the HDD. If the SSD is smaller, I recommend `gparted`'s copy and paste functions (you need to re-install the bootloader, tough).

Answer (score 0):

Two things to consider are the block size and, as you mentioned, any optimizations the filesystem has for SSD's.

Partionion tools can show you the block size, so you can compare them. You can also check `dmesg`. For the filesystem, check it's `mkfs.*` documentation for flags used for SSD's.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do this:  A block-level copy (dd if=/dev/hdd of=/dev/ssd etc) or a file-level copy (rsync -aAXv /mnt/hdd/ /mnt/ssd).

The block level copy is simpler; all you have to do is make sure the destination disk is bigger than the source disk and run a dd command.  But it's possible that you end up with the blocks in the filesystem not lining-up properly with the blocks in the SSD--writing one FS block would require writing the second half of one SSD block and the first half of the next, degrading performance and increasing wear.

The file-level copy is a little more complicated; you have to recreate your partitions on the new drive, mount them, run the copy, and maybe adjust your fstab.  But it also gives you a lot more flexibility to change partition size/format, and makes block misalignment much less likely.

The third option is to just do a reinstall of the OS and copy only your data, which is probably simpler, especially if you were thinking of upgrading anyways.

Comment: I haven't voted on this Answer yet, but I don't see where you address the two aspects of the Question: "recommended fstab settings; mkfs or partition tools"